# Syntax error on new WebSocket in edge, internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

So I think I am getting crazy.

I use javaScript to make a WebSocket connection on port 443.

The problem is that the WebSocket declaration is throwing a SyntaxError only on edge and internet explorer browsers, on other browsers like Chrome and Firefox it works perfectly.

The code that I use:

```
var Connection;
Connection = new WebSocket("ws:/127.0.0.1:443");
```

[image: Console Edge Error]
[image: Critical Code In Edge]

Does someone knows what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to:

```
var connection = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:443");
```

Comment: Still not working ..., it is saying the same error on this line.

Comment: even this `("ws://127.0.0.1:443")` ?

Comment: wow great now it is working, if I use "connection" and not "Connection" , it is working in 2 lines as well..., I don't understand why? It is like "Connection" is a keywords in edge/Internet explorer.

Comment: usually anything that's starts with uppercase is an constructors so IE count Connection as a constructors

Comment: was it resolved because you changed `ws:/` to `ws://`?

Comment: Is there a polyfill for this?

Answer (score 1):

This issue comes from the `webpackHotDevClient.js` file (line 60)

> ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js:60

Add `slashes: true,` to the format object to solve it, your update should look like the following snippet:

```js
// Connect to WebpackDevServer via a socket.
var connection = new WebSocket(
  url.format({
    protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws',
    hostname: window.location.hostname,
    port: window.location.port,
    // Hardcoded in WebpackDevServer
    pathname: '/sockjs-node',
    slashes: true,
  })
);
```