# RXJS websocket not working in internet explorer 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, websocket, rxjs

I have a websocket that is being used for signing of an online application. It works fine in Chrome, however, when using the same code in IE11 I get a syntax error.

I am using rxjs WebSocketSubject

```
import {webSocket, WebSocketSubject} from 'rxjs/webSocket';
```

I have been able to isolate the error to this line of code:

```
this.signingSocket$ = webSocket(socketUrl);
```

using the *awesome* debugger in IE11 i have found that this is the code that is causing problems:

```
try {
o=t?new l(i,t):new l(i),this._socket=o,r&&(this._socket.binaryType=r)
} catch(s){
return void u.error(s)
}
```

**o=t?new l(i,t):new l(i)** is marked by the debugger as the issue

I can only see the minified version as I can not reproduce this error locally due to strict boundries set by my administration.

I assume it is a polyfill issue but I'm not sure what to add.

these are my polyfills:

```
import 'classlist.js';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'core-js';
import 'element-closest-polyfill';
import 'polyfill-array-includes';
import 'es7-object-polyfill';
```

I added core-js to see if that would solve the issue, with no success.

Comment: I use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transform your code, it gives this result: `o = t ? new l(i, t) : new l(i), (void 0)._socket = o, r && ((void 0)._socket.binaryType = r);`. You could try with this code. If the issue persists, please provide [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with virtual values that you pass in this line so that we can have a test and have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: The bolded code in question comes from the rxjs npm package, my understanding is that I will not be able change that piece of code

Comment: I see. I found [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667587/syntax-error-on-new-websocket-in-edge-internet-explorer) and you can refer to it. You can check the format of the url value you pass in according to the accepted answer.